# How can i update the uv map after modifying the object?

Tags: uv

Similar questions have been asked but i couldn't find one fitting my situation. So i've reshaped a boot model to be used with a new series of textures. Every single vertex has been moved. How do i correctly update the uv map? i've tried unwrapping the mesh again but it repositions the islands (in picture: left - original, right - unwrapped). how do i get it to respect the original layout or update the map without unwrapping?
thank you
[image]

Comment: You can bake all textures from old mesh to new UV map. Choose old mesh with right textures, select new mesh (adjusted) and bake textures in "from selected" mode.

Comment: could you please provide a step-by-step?

Answer (score 1):

**ALT + RMB** to select *Original mesh*

**ALT + SHIFT + RMB** to select *New mesh*

[image]

**TAB** to enter *Edit mode*

**A** to select *all*

Open *UV Editor* menu

Press **+** button to add new image, you may want to increase default resolution or leave as is, then click OK

[image]

In *Render Tab* find *Bake* menu and click Bake

[image]

[image]

Comment: i did as instructed and all it got me was a black UV map screen with the same unchanged mapping layout.

Comment: It is hard to tell what is wrong without actual .blend file. Also this method is more suited for objects with similar shape, because baking depends on distance and it will go bad, if there is some inersecting geometry between meshes.